# Как распарсить html и засунуть в текст со свойствами?

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть html примерно такого вида(может быть и другой).

```
"<strong>Информация</strong><br><br>еще текст<br>Опять какая то информация"
```

Я хочу брать текст из тегов, и исходя из тегов давать тексту стиль. Как это реализовать в WPF стандартными контролами? Если нельзя, то как создать кастомный.

Мне нужно не только распарсить, а еще как то применить стиль в зависимости от того, что в HTML.
p.s это для тех кто закрывает вопрос

Comment: Для отображения HTML в WPF есть контролы-браузеры.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/wpf

Comment: Можете сделать свой парсер и юзерконтрол. Парсите html и получаете список: `<strong>Text</strong>`, `<br>`, `<br>`. Сделать промежуточный класс который имеет свойства текста, шрифты, фонты, аттрибуты html. Его уже путем преобразования можно накидать всякие font-ы, бордеры итп в WPF контроле. Ну и некоторые элементы типа `<br>` заменяете на `Environment.NewLine`

Comment: Ну полное преобразование сделать нереально. С нуля же тоже морока. Ищите разные WPF RichTextBox + html или WPF Html Editor вроде [такого](https://github.com/ngaillet/WPF-RichText-Editor)

Comment: это эдитор, а мне нужен textblock воспринимающий html

Comment: Текстблоков, воспринимающих HTML, не существует, как минимум потому что для этого есть браузер, который легко встраивается в приложение. Считайте, что браузер - это и есть тот самый контрол, который понимает HTML. Если это вам не подходит, то я не понимаю, почему.

Comment: потому что когда таких браузеров 500-700(а именно столько текстов html должно быть), приложение жрет много памяти

Comment: Зачем пользовтелю одновременно смотреть 500-700 текстов? Они на экран же не влезут. Если вам нужно что-то очень простое, то достаточно распарсить HTML в объектную модель, любым парсером и на ее основе собрать `TextBlock` https://stackoverflow.com/a/5263094/12888024